# XML file displays different than it's source in IE

Tags: windows-explorer, internet-explorer

I have a very weird problem that can't wrap my head around here.

We have a folder with an XML language file for which we just received an updated files.
So we have overwritten the old one.

Now When we open that XML file in IE it's content is displayed, however the content that is displayed is the older version of this file that was overwritten.

When I right click and choose 'View source' the newer correct version is shown.

If I rename the file, and open it in IE the correct version is also shown.

It does not happen with Chrome or Firefox.

The problem is that the language file is read by an application, which also reads the older version, so renaming it is not an option.

I have already deleted the cache, and did a disk cleanup removing all temporary files. The problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, the XML rendering component of IE is a separate process/addin, although I am really not sure why you are getting this.

I would try to close all open instances of Internet Explorer, then load up Internet Options from control panel and try to clear your cache again.

Also check Task Manager that there are no other Internet Explorer instances open (and no programs with XML in their name).

Then try to relaunch.

Also, try a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, instead of a standard refresh next time you on the page.

I hope this helps, but I fear it won't as I can't replicate this issue... I will delete if someone comes up with a better answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried `Ctrl+F5`, it didn't work. We ended up re-installing the entire application to a different folder.